# binomial test for testing significance of classification very sensitive to hits count

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, statistical-significance, binomial-distribution, multi-class

I'm doing a multi-class classification task and I wonder if I'm doing the binomial test correctly since it is very sensitive to the count of correctly classified trials (hits count).

Say, there are 20k trials and 3 classes. I calculate the p value as

`p(#hits) = 1-binocdf(#hits,20k,3)`

Then it seems to me, that the p value is very sensitive to comparibly small changes in #hits compared to total trials of 20k.

`p(6700) = 0.31` while `6700/20k = 33.50%`

`p(6750) = 0.10` while `6750/20k = 33.75%`

`p(6800) = 0.02` while `6800/20k = 34.00%`

Is it correct this way and I shouldn't be confused that this somehow is against my intuition or am I doing somethin wrong?
So if I assume a 5% significance level, 6750 hits are not signifikant, but 6800 are?

I guess this behaviour becomes even more prominent when there are more classes.

Comment: I think your intuition is wrong. The chance level is 20000/3 = 6666 hits. So 6750 hits are 84 hits away from chance, whereas 6800 hits are 134 hits away -- that is a large difference, enough to reduce p-value from 0.1 to 0.02.